# 2D moving objects in angle

Tags: javascript, html

Im making simple 2D space shooter with use of html5 and JavaScript.

The idea is simple, shoot down as many aliens as you can.

I made it to the point where I have player which can move and rotate, but I want the player to move in the angle, like 80s Asteroids (you set angle then press forward key and ship goes forward in that angle)

[image]

my movement now is simple:

```
up = y -= speed * delta time
down y += speed * delta time 
left x -= speed * delta time
right x += speed * delta time
```

my rotation is made like this:

```
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(this.x + this.w / 2, this.y + this.h / 2);
ctx.rotate(this.angle); 
Draw.Rect(ctx,this.w /2 * (-1),this.h / 2 * (-1),this.w,this.h,"red",1);//context,x,y,w,h,color,opacity
ctx.restore();
```

angle:

```
if(keys.e)this.angle += 0.1;
if(keys.q)this.angle -= 0.1;
```

Comment: You're more likely to get an answer if you make you make it explicit what you're looking for. I had to read this question twice to see that info. It looks like you're close. Depends on how fancy you want to get. Assuming positive y is up and 90 degrees means go straight up and 0 degrees means go straight to the right, something as simple as y += speed * cos(angle), x += speed * sin(angle) should work, though you may prefer to handle that by composing translate and rotate commands (I'd have to think about the right way to do that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Simple Approach: Sin and Cos**

It looks like you're close. If you want to keep it simple, and assuming positive y is up and 90 degrees means go straight up and 0 degrees means go straight to the right, something as simple as **y += speed * sin(angle), x += speed * cos(angle)** should work.

Comment: It works, thank you for solution and sorry for bad english explanation of my problem.
[video of rotation](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14ddqryBSkeChpUVVyBU02Ab219QqJrY7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Great! Glad it helped! Regarding my comment about the question, I only meant that you might want to repeat the specific thing you’re looking for in the body of the question and not just rely on the title.

Comment: By the way don’t forget to choose an answer whenever you feel one has answered your question.